# Tablesorters addparse gives "undefined is not a function "

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

Tablesorter isn't acception .addParser somehow. I get the error "undefined is not a function".
This is my code:

```
 $('mytable').tablesorter({
    sortList: [[0,0]],
    sortRestart: true,
    initialized: function(table) {
        var currentTable = $(table);
        var startcol = currentTable.data("startcol");
        if (startcol) {
            var sorting = [[startcol, 0]];
            currentTable.trigger("sorton", [sorting]);
        }
    },
    headers:
    {
        4: { sorter: 'customparse' },
        5: { sorter: 'customparse' }
    }
}).addParser({
    id: 'customparse',
    is: function (s) {
        return false;
    },
    format: function (s) {
        console.log(s);
        return s.replace(/\s+/g, '').replace(/,/g, '.');
    },
    type: 'numeric'
});
```

I found some other related questions and cant find my issue.. I've doubble check that jQuery isnt included twice. It works fine without addPareser even thought the jQuery version Im using is 1.11. But I tried updating to version 2.1 but no change..

Am I initiating it wrong? what am I doing wrong..

Comment: I hope you mistyped and you use **1.11**, not **1.1**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add a parser, you need to use `$.tablesorter.addParser()`.  You cannot access the method from a jQuery object, as you're trying to do.

Comment: Fastest answer, thanks a lot! Was confusing settings and adding new condition (like what addparser does).

Answer (score 2):

Because you are adding the parser wrong

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({ ... });
```

[Documentation Example](http://tablesorter.com/docs/example-parsers.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: 'customparse',
    is: function (s) {
        return false;
    },
    format: function (s) {
        console.log(s);
        return s.replace(/\s+/g, '').replace(/,/g, '.');
    },
    type: 'numeric'
});
```

Do the above before you instantiate the tablesorter on your table.